# Как наиболее просто сделать генератор задач для судоку?

Tags: разработка-игр

Нужно средство для создания задач судоку, а не для решения их.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Взять заведомо правильную судоку.
2. Перемешать столбцы в пределах блоков.
3. Перемешать столбцы-блоки.
4. Перемешать строки в пределах блоков.
5. Перемешать строки-блоки.
6. Перенумеровать цифры.

Полученная в результате задача будет равноценна исходной, но внешне будет выглядеть другой.